# Is "shh" a word and why?

Tags: is-it-a-word, interjections, onomatopoeia, exclamations, parts-of-speech

Is *shh* a word?

- If it is, why is it a word?
- If it is not, why isn't it a word?

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shh

Comment: [This article at ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/are-there-any-english-words-with-no-vowels) claims that candidates such as _sh, brrr, hmm_ should be labelled 'words'. But I can't agree with them  that words such has _cwm_ and _crwth_ have no vowel; they have the rare vowel usage of w (from the Welsh). / Wordness depends on acceptance into the lexicon, which is itself dependent on frequency of use (and how often dictionary usage panels sit). These are all well used; absence of a vowel is not usually considered a factor in deciding wordness.

Comment: Those can be said as words by looking over the growth of usage of those words.

Comment: I’m afraid you’re going to have to tell us what you mean by “classified as a word”. What’s a word? Whose definition? Who’s doing the classifying here, and what is there purpose for doing so? One thing I’m sure it’s not is a ham sandwich. I’m sure it isn’t a ham sandwich, which probably means it’s a word instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Shh is a word**.  According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/word), a word is:

> a speech sound or series of speech sounds that symbolizes and
>   communicates a meaning usually without being divisible into smaller
>   units capable of independent use.

M-W further says:

> any segment of written or printed discourse ordinarily appearing
>   between spaces or between a space and a punctuation mark

*Shh* satisfies both definitions of a word.  If I tell you "shh" you know what I mean (first definition). As for the second definition:

> Jane, shh!

Comment: The second definition uses "any", so shh clearly fits.  The first uses "a" rather than "any", which at least implies that some examples might not be a word.  That aside, I spot checked a bunch of dictionary definitions and all of them treat it like a word.